# How to summarize in the Ui5 / fiori table JSONModel

Tags: sapui5

I am writing a simple application which aims to display the local data of a json file.
How can I sum the values ​​from a column?

Expected effect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lttSt.png)

**Below are the files to recreate the case**

V_Root.view.xml

```
    <mvc:View controllerName="Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Root" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
        <App id="V_Main">
            <pages>
                <Page title="Root View">
                    <content></content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
</mvc:View>
```

V_Source.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Source"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="Soruce View">
                <content>
                    <VBox width="100%" direction="Column" id="__vbox0">
                        <items>
                            <Button text="Button 1" width="100px" id="__button2" press="GoToTarget_1"/>
                            <Button text="Button 2" width="100px" id="__button3" press="GoToTarget_2"/>
                        </items>
                    </VBox>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

V_Target_1.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Target_1"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="Target One" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="GoOneScreenBack">
                <content>
                    <ScrollContainer vertical="true" focusable="true" height="95%">
                        <Table id="namiot" items="{path: '/namiot'}">
                            <columns>
                                <Column width="12rem">
                                    <Label text="Najem"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column minScreenWidth="tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                    <Label text="Price"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column width="12rem">
                                    <Label text="Total Cost"/>
                                    <footer>
                                        <Text text="Sum:"/>
                                    </footer>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <ColumnListItem>
                                <Text text="{ProductType}"></Text>
                                <Text text="{ProductPrice}"></Text>
                                <Text text="{ProductTotal}"></Text>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </Table>
                    </ScrollContainer>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

V_Root.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Root", {
        onInit: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

V_Source.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Source", {

        /**
         * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
         * Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Source
         */
        onInit: function () {

        },
        GoToTarget_1: function () {
            // Now Get the Router Info
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

            // Tell the Router to Navigate To Route_Tar_1
            oRouter.navTo("Route_Tar_1", {});
        },
        GoToTarget_2: function () {
            // Now Get the Router Info
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

            // Tell the Router to Navigate To Route_Tar_2
            oRouter.navTo("Route_Tar_2", {});
        }

        /**
         * Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
         * (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Source
         */
        //  onBeforeRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
         * This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Source
         */
        //  onAfterRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Source
         */
        //  onExit: function() {
        //
        //  }

    });

});
```

V_Target_1.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "Nawigacja/ZNavigation/formatter/Formatter"
], function (Controller, History,formatter) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("Nawigacja.ZNavigation.controller.V_Target_1", {

        /**
         * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
         * Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Target_1
         */
        onInit: function () {
            
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("namiot");
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("model/namiot.json");
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        },
        
        
        GoOneScreenBack: function (Evt) {

            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
            // Go one screen back if you find a Hash
            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            }
            // If you do not find a correct Hash, go to the Source screen using default router;
            else {
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.navTo("", true);
            }
        },
        formatter: formatter

        /**
         * Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
         * (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Target_1
         */
        //  onBeforeRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
         * This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Target_1
         */
        //  onAfterRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
         * @memberOf Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Target_1
         */
        //  onExit: function() {
        //
        //  }

    });

});
```

models.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/Device"
], function (JSONModel, Device) {
    "use strict";

    return {

        createDeviceModel: function () {
            var oModel = new JSONModel(Device);
            oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
            return oModel;
        }

    };
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "Nawigacja.ZNavigation",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
            "version": "1.40.12"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "flexEnabled": false,
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view.V_Root",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "V_Root"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.65.6",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "Nawigacja.ZNavigation.i18n.i18n"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [{
                "uri": "css/style.css"
            }]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "Nawigacja.ZNavigation.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "V_Main",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "routes": [{
                "name": "Route_Source",
                "pattern": "",
                "target": ["Target_Source"],
                "titleTarget": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Route_Tar_1",
                "pattern": "V_Target_1",
                "titleTarget": "",
                "greedy": false,
                "target": ["Target_1"]
            }, {
                "name": "Route_Tar_2",
                "pattern": "V_Target_2",
                "titleTarget": "",
                "greedy": false,
                "target": ["Target_2"]
            }],
            "targets": {
                "Target_1": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "V_Target_1",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "Target_2": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation":"true",
                    "viewName": "V_Target_2",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "Target_Source": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "clearAggregation":"true",
                    "viewName": "V_Source",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

namiot.json

```
{
    "namiot":[
    {
        "ProductName": "Product1",
        "ProductType": "Type1",
        "ProductPrice": "25",
        "ProductTotal": "5000",
        "Productadd": "",
        "ProductaddPr":""
    },
    {
        "ProductName": "Product2",
        "ProductType": "Type2",
        "ProductPrice": "25",
        "ProductTotal": "5000",
        "Productadd": "",
        "ProductaddPr":""
    }

    
    
    
    
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are probably x options to realize this.

You could use the method **attachUpdateFinished** which will be called when the Tablebinding get's updated (the table receives the Items). Then you can summarize the values and store it in an JSONModel and bind it to the **footertext**. When the binding (the items) change the sum would be updated.

```js
oTable.attachUpdateFinished(function (oEvt) {
     var iSum = 0;
     var aItems = oEvt.getSource().getItems();
     for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
     var oItem = aItems[i].getBindingContext().getObject();
     iSum = iSum + parseFloat(oItem.ProductTotal);
     }
        //Do whatever you want with the iSum  
     });
```

Here's an example how it could be realized.
[Code Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/uzh84x5n/14/)